# Error: The method finish() is undefined for the type SovmestnaRab

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class SovmestnaRab extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sovmesna_rab, null);
        return v;
        }

     public void onClick(View v) {

            this.finish();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
```

Ошибка возникает тут:

```
this.finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
```

Код ошибки:

```
The method finish() is undefined for the type SovmestnaRab.
```

и

```
The constructor Intent(SovmestnaRab, Class<OneActivity>) is undefined.
```

В других классах работало все, а тут не хочет. Что я сделала не так?

Comment: у Фрагмента нету метода finish(). об этом вам и говорит компилятор

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В других классах работало все, а тут
> не хочет. Что я сделала не так?

Я так понимаю, работало в `Activity`? А у вас тут `Fragment`.

А про:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);
```

Напишите:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), OneActivity.class);
```

Comment: Да. Я могу из фрагмента переходить на другие классы?

Comment: @Imire, в другие Activity или другие Fragment'ы? Ответ на оба вопроса, собственно, да, можете. Но механизм перехода разный.

Comment: Из фрагмента в активити, как это сделать?

Comment: @Imireб написал же: Intent intent = new Intent(this, OneActivity.class);